# Error al Leer un archivo .txt con texto y números . C++

Tags: c++

Como puedo leer un archivo .txt (caracteres y números delimitados por un "-") y mostrarlo por consola.

Tengo un error en getline que no pude resolver.

Datos del txt:
01054 - Jose Martinez - San Martin 549, La Puerta, Catamarca -  043 ;

Quisiera poder leer el archivo txt y guardarlo en un TDA de Usuarios.

Este es mi código:

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

fstream archivo; // declarar archivo

struct Usuario{
int id;
string nombreYApellido;
string direccion;
int edad;

}

void leerArchivo1(){

    archivo.open("usuarios_test.txt",ios::in);  // **ios::in es para leer el archivo de salida**                         
   
 char delimitador = '-';
    if(archivo.is_open()){
        string linea;
        int id;
        string nombreYApellido;
        string direccion;
        int edad;
            while(getline(archivo,linea))
                {

                    stringstream stream(linea);
                    string nombreYApellido,direccion;
                    int id,edad;

                    getline(stream,id,delimitador);
                    getline(stream,nombreYApellido,delimitador);
                    getline(stream,direccion,delimitador);
                    getline(stream,edad,delimitador);


                    cout<<"------------"<<endl;
                    cout<<"Id: "<<id<<endl;
                    cout<<"Nombre y apellido:"<<nombreYApellido<<endl;
                    cout<<"Direccion:"<<direccion<<endl;
                    cout<<"Edad :"<<edad<<endl;




            }
        archivo.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Lo siento no se encontro el archivo...";
    }

}


int main()
{
   leerArchivo1();
   system("pause");
    return 0;
}`
```

introducir el código aquí

[image: imagen]

Comment: Te falto `#include <string>`. Y `<string.h>` debería ser `<cstring>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La firma de `std::getline` es:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& getline( std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>&& input,
                                           std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
                                           CharT delim );
```

Si asumimos que la plantilla está usando como flujo de datos un archivo y caracteres estrechos en la cadena de lectura, la firma se resumiría así:

```
std::ifstream& getline( std::ifstream&& input, std::string& str, char delim );
```

Es decir, el primer parámetro es un flujo de datos de entrada, el segundo parámetro es una cadena de caracteres y el tercero es un carácter. En dos de tus cuatro llamadas a la función, los parámetros no coinciden:

```
getline(stream,id,delimitador);
//             ^^
//              \___ 'id' es un entero (int) se esperaba std::string.
getline(stream,edad,delimitador);
//             ^^^^
//               \___ 'edad' es un entero (int) se esperaba std::string.
```

Tienes que leer texto y después transformarlo en número, además tienes que evitar las siguientes malas prácticas o errores:

1. **No incluyas cabeceras que no usas**: No estás usando nada de las cabeceras `<cstdlib>` y `<string.h>`.
2. **No incluyas cabeceras de C en código C++**: La cabecera `<string.h>` es de C.
3. **No uses variables globales**: Las variables deben definirse todo lo cerca de su punto de uso como sea posible.
4. **La cláusula `using namespace std`**: Debe usarse en el ámbito lo más pequeño posible.
5. **Las estructuras y clases**: Al declararse o definirse deben acabar en punto y coma (`;`).

Si corregimos esas malas prácticas y usamos las recomendaciones de C++ moderno, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Usuario{
    int id;
    std::string nombreYApellido;
    std::string direccion;
    int edad;
};

// Operador de lectura de datos desde archivo
std::ifstream &operator >>(std::ifstream &i, Usuario &u) {
    using namespace std;

    string linea;
    getline(i, linea); // Leemos el registro completo

    stringstream registro(linea);
    getline(registro, linea, '-'); // id
    u.id = atoi(linea.c_str());

    getline(registro, u.nombreYApellido, '-'); // nombreYApellido
    getline(registro, u.direccion, '-'); // direccion

    getline(registro, linea, '-'); // edad
    u.edad= atoi(linea.c_str());

    return i;
}

// Operador de escritura de datos
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Usuario &u) {
    return o
        << "Id: " << u.id << '\n'
        << "Nombre y apellido:" << u.nombreYApellido << '\n'
        << "Direccion:" << u.direccion << '\n'
        << "Edad :" << u.edad;
}

void leerArchivo1(){
    using namespace std;

    // ifstream es explicitamente de lectura ('i'nput 'f'ile 'stream'), no hace falta usar ios::in
    // si falla la apertura del archivo, no se entra en el if
    if (std::ifstream archivo{"usuarios_test.txt"}) {
        Usuario u;
        while (archivo >> u) {
            cout << "------------\n" << u << '\n';
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Lo siento no se encontro el archivo...";
    }
}

int main()
{
    leerArchivo1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte  y tomarte el tiempo de aclararme muchas dudas. Definitivamente logré solucionarlo utilizando la función atoi.